# Group records by Month and Year

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table

```
| inquiry_id | supplier_id | created             |
 ------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2           | 2012-10-19 03:10:29 |
 ------------------------------------------------ 
| 2          | 2           | 2012-10-17 04:11:23 |
 ------------------------------------------------
| 3          | 2           | 2012-09-19 03:15:11 |
 ------------------------------------------------
| 4          | 2           | 2012-09-7 01:16:32  |
 ------------------------------------------------
```

I want to have a mysql result like,

```
| Month - Year | Total Inquiry |
--------------------------------
| 10-2013      | 2             |
--------------------------------
| 09-2013      | 2             |       
--------------------------------
```

How can I do this using MySQL?

Comment: Thanks @Blade0rz those links really works

Answer (score 7):

Use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function for that:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created,'%m-%Y') AS Month_Year
     , COUNT(inquiry_id) AS Total_Inquiry
FROM Table1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created,'%m-%Y')
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dfb7/7)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created,'%m-%Y'), COUNT(inquiry_id) 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY YEAR(created), MONTH(created)
```

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18781/10)